# Material UI React — Select text wrap for long strings in menu (mobile/desktop)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a few long strings in an MUI Select component. Is there any way to add a text-wrap or something similar to make sure the width doesn't exceed and doesn't cut off in mobile.

Desktop:

[image]

Mobile:

[image]

```
<FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: '100%', marginLeft: 0, padding: 0 }}>
  <Select
    value={prompt}
    onChange={handleChange}
    displayEmpty
    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Without label' }}
    sx={{'bgcolor': 'rgba(139, 139, 139, 0.3)', color: 'white', border: '1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)', minWidth: '100%', marginLeft: 0, padding: 0}}
  >
    {prompts.map((prompt, i) => <MenuItem value={i}>{prompt}</MenuItem>)}
  </Select>
```

`prompt` is a string[].

How can I style the select menu? **Is there any way to make sure the dropdown width doesn't exceed the `Select` width?**

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to get multi-line / wrapping menu items when setting white-space to normal

in CSS:

```
white-space: normal;
```

or as inline style in the Mui component (or via some sx prop I guess)

```
 <MenuItem style={{whiteSpace: 'normal'}} value={i}>{prompt}</MenuItem>
```

Comment: yup that kind of works ... but is there anyway to make sure the dropdown width is equal to the `Select` width?

Comment: It should be possible to set the width of the drop-down menu, but even without doing that, the drop-down should fill as much as it can/should since it's content will wrap.

Comment: I think the strings will wrap to 2 lines even if we limit the width, could you show my how to limit the width since the formcontrol is 100%?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
    const inputRef = useRef();


    <Select
        inputProps={{ ref: ref => (inputRef.current = ref?.node) }}
        MenuProps={{ sx: { width: inputRef.current.offsetWidth }}}>
        //your options here
    </Select>
```